# Flutter : Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run. You are currently using Java 11

Tags: java, flutter, stripe-payments

I have been trying to upgrade the [flutter_stripe](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe) package to version 10.0.0 and it requires gradle 8.0 0r higher... so I upgraded gradle and now i keep getting this error and cant run my app :(

here is how my debug console looks like :

```
Launching lib\main.dart on 21121119SG in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\morsv\Documents\Flutter Projects\book_door\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run. You are currently using Java 11.
      Your current JDK is located in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
      You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Exited (1).
```

I tried changing the java version in IDE settings and tried Adding java 17 to my environment variables and tried editing the gradle.properties file but NOTHING WORKED ... am I doing something wrong? (i am using vscode btw is there a special way to change the jdk for vscode?)

Comment: It says "Your current JDK is located in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre" Did you upgrade to 17 in Android Studio?

Comment: yes its up to date, after updating it i get this error now : The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle

change

```
compileOptions {
   sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
   targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11' 
    }
```

to

```
compileOptions {
   sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
   targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17' 
    }
```

Try updating gradle if doesn't work

Comment: Thank you for the response! i ended up uninstalling android studio and reinstalling it again and that solved the issue.